# ArrayIndexOutofBounds exception?

Tags: java

My code is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{

   int i=0;
   textedit<String> q=new textedit<String>();
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   int linestoread=sc.nextInt();
   String[] a12=new String[linestoread];
   for(i=0;i<linestoread;i++);
{
   a12[i]=sc.nextLine(); //Line 169
   q.insert(a12[i]);
}
   for(String s1:q)
   System.out.println(s1);

}
}
```

The above code throws an `ArrayIndexOutofBounds` exception as soon an input is given for the `linestoread` variable.The exception is thrown at line 169. I don't know what's wrong with the code.

I have just posted the part of the code which causes the problem.

Comment: please provide the full stack trace whenever you have a question that includes an unwanted exception.

Comment: @amit Yeah I would but last time when I posted the entire code I got comments telling me to post only what's necessary and actually it makes sense!!!

Comment: @user1613360 by "full stack trace" he means, the error message, not the code.

Comment: The stacktrace is not the code. If you get an exception, it's usually best to put it as well, it's not hard to go over it, but gives readers a lot of information about the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:

```
--------------------------V
                          V
for(i=0;i<linestoread;i++);
{
   a12[i]=sc.nextLine(); //Line 169
   q.insert(a12[i]);
}
```

The semicolon is extraneous and should be removed

The for-loop does nothing and the block following is executed once, with the variable `i` set to one more than the index of the last element, causing the exception.

Comment: Oh great thanks and I know it's a silly mistake but I am curious to know what made my program to compile and no error was thrown even though it is a syntax error?

Comment: @user1613360, no it's not a syntax error rather a logical error. that's a empty loop.

Comment: It is not a syntax error. The loop body is empty, which is completely valid.

Comment: @user1613360 Because it is not a syntax error, it is completely valid

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
for(i=0;i<linestoread;i++) { } //This will be executed until `i` 
                               //reach linestoread
{
   a12[i]=sc.nextLine();       //Here, `i = linestoread`, which is OOB
   q.insert(a12[i]);
}
```

Remove the `;` after the `for` loop. When the loop is finished, you try to access `i` which is equal to `linestoread`, which will result in this exception.

Answer (score -4):

The for loop should be

for(i = 0; i < linestoread - 1; i++)

But not

for(i = 0; i < linestoread; i++) //leads to array index out of bound exception for last value.

And plz don't place semicolon after for syntax :)

Comment: This is totally wrong, `i < linestoread` is just fine, do the calculations. (`i <= linestoread` is wrong)

Comment: ... and the semicolon has nothing to do with syntax.